# How to run Tor Network in Google Colab?

Tags: terminal, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, tor

Lets be Honest, Google Colab's Terminal gave me a Lot of Power and Potential. But there is one thing that I cannot and **How can I Install Tor Network in Google Colab** Although, I can Install and run both tor and torghost in terminal but there is a Problem, it says IP Tables not set and I have researched on this for Months but could not find any answers. If anyone can Pull this off you are a Legend.

So, here is a Quick Summary to the testing I have done so Far,

- IP Tables are not in Google Colab.
- We need to somehow set the IP Tables in a way that we both get connected to the runtime and its IP Dosent change for Google Colab Services but the traffic comming and going out should be through Tor.

**HELP NEEDED**

Comment: Umm, we can use ngrok to forward traffic, and then pass the ngrok tunnel to an OpenVPN Server which passes through tor.